# How to cast a variable extracted from a payload in citrus framework?

Tags: java, integration-testing, citrus-framework

I'm creating IT tests with [Citrus Framework](http://www.citrusframework.org/). I have two calls to the server, one for creating a user and another one for performing some operation with that user.

Problem: I need a value from the create user request that is not a String, to put it in the request of the second call. Extraction of the value:

```
new SoapActionBuilder()
         .client(webServiceClient)
         .receive()
         .namespace("ns", MY_NAMESPACE)
         .extractFromPayload("//ns:someId", "someId")
```

And then this *someId* has to be used for building the next request. If it was a String it would be:

```
request.setSomeId("${someId}");
```

But it is a Long, so doing the casting doesn't work (Citrus resolves that value later on, and Long#valueOf is executed in that very moment):

```
request.setSomeId(Long.valueOf("${someId}"));
```

**Is there any way to easily cast that variable (maybe on extraction)?**

I manage to do it with a JavaAction, but is very weird for using it regularly (3 lines and a new method are needed). It's something like:

```
public void test() {
    ...
    action(new JavaActionBuilder(new JavaAction().setInstance(this))
            .method("setSomeId")
            .methodArgs(request, "${someId}"));

    ...
}
public void setSomeId(Request request, String someId) {
    request.setSomeId(Long.valueOf(someId));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to access test variable objects in a TestDesigner is to do so in a test action. The Citrus test designer has a design time where the complete test case is constructed. Later on at runtime the test is executed and your XPath expression is evaluated to the test variable. So you may add a new test action like this:

```
action(new AbstractTestAction() {
    @Override
    public void doExecute(TestContext context) {
        Long someId = Long.valueOf(context.getVariable("someId"));
        // do something with someId
    }
}
```

In contrast to that you could use the Citrus TestRunner which does not have a separate design time. However you must access the Citrus TestContext in order to read the variable as long value.

Comment: Thanks @christoph, I did something based on that idea, a separated class with a consumer and a variable, so execution is invoking the consumer with the value of the variable